# Conditional SetEnv in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, pyrocms, setenv

Is it possible to set a SetEnv variable in an .htaccess file differently depending on hostname?

For example, I need my `.htaccess` file to have the following value:

```
SetEnv PYRO_ENV production
```

On production boxes, and...

```
SetEnv PYRO_ENV stage
```

On staging boxes. The `.htaccess` file is version controlled, which is the reason I'm looking for a conditional solution.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

For conditional settings there is [SetEnvIf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif):

```
SetEnvIf Host ^stage\.example\.com$ PYRO_ENV=stage
SetEnvIf Host ^(www\.)?example\.com$ PYRO_ENV=production
```

Comment: So useful for Magento as well: `SetEnvIf Host \.de MAGE_RUN_CODE=de` (in our case we have internal and external URLs: `example.de` as well as `example.de.testing.local`) - so this works for both.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 25):

You can, with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stage\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:stage]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=PYRO_ENV:production]
```

Comment: That is awesome. Thank you! For others who may come across this answer in the future, more documentation can be found on setting environment variables here: [ModRewrite Flags Env](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e) and [Environment Variables in Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html)